# How to Install Provising Profile and Certificates in Project By Command line / Using shell Script

Tags: ios, iphone, bash, ipad, provisioning-profile

I want to add my certificates and provisioning profile in my Project via Terminal/Using Shell script but I cant able to found any code for it.I also Want to access Keychain Access via code. or can we access Build settings of Xcode Using Commands.

Comment: I would look into the fastlane tools: https://fastlane.tools/, particularly the sigh set of tools: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/sigh#readme

Comment: okay but Whenever I try to access fastlane its give me error like "fastlane: command not found" I already install it in my gem

Comment: they give me suggestion to "Select a provisioning profile for the "Debug" build configuration in the project editor." but I dont want to set it through Editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

command For install .cer/.p12 file is

```
security unlock-keychain -p "" ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
security import XXX.cer -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain -P "" -T /usr/bin/codesign
```

and for add Provision Profile

```
output="~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/$uuid.mobileprovision"
cp -R  "$mp" "$output"
```